# useRoute() in Vue 3 Composition API with Typescript - [Vue warn]: injection "Symbol(route location)" not found using Typescript and

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, vue-router4

I've recently upgraded a Vue 2 app that that uses Vue Router and is mostly in typescript to Vue 3. When I migrated a function that reads the route from Options API, using this.$route to the Composition API using useRoute() the component load failed with the error:

```
[Vue warn]: injection "Symbol(route location)" not found. 
  at <Content pageName="homepage" onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< viewRef > > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <Website>
```

I've stripped the app down as possible to avoid any confounding issues and here's what I'm running the gets the error.

I'm running with:
"vue": "^3.3.4",
"vue-router": "^4.2.1",

This is the entry code

```
website.js
import { createApp } from "vue"
import router from "./routes/router.js"
import Website from "./website.vue"
const app = createApp(Website)
app.use(router)
app.mount("#shop")
```

then here's the base component:

```
website.vue
<template lang="pug">
router-view
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue"
export default defineComponent({
    name: "Website"
})
```

the router:

```
router.js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router"
import Content from "../components/content.vue"

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes: [
        {
            path: "/",
            components: {
                default: Content,
                },
            props: {
                default: { pageName: "homepage" }
            },
    ]
})

export default router
```

then the active component that works like this in Options API:

```
content.vue
<template lang="pug">
h1 {{ myroute.fullPath }}
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "Content",
    props: {
        pageName: { 
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    },
    computed: {
        myroute() {
            return this.$route
        }   
    }
}
</script>
```

Using Composition API this works

```
content.vue
<template lang="pug">
h1 {{ myroute.fullPath }}
</template>

<script>
import { useRoute } from "vue-router"

export default {
    name: "Content",
    props: {
        pageName: { 
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    },
    setup(props) {
        const route = useRoute()
        return {
            myroute: route
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

But when I switch to TS like this:

```
content.vue
<template lang="pug">
h1 {{ myroute.fullPath }}
</template>

<script lang="ts>
import { useRoute } from "vue-router"
import { defineComponent } from "vue"

export default defineComponent ({
    name: "Content",
    props: {
        pageName: { 
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    },
    setup(props) {
        const route = useRoute()
        return {
            myroute: route
        }
    }
})
</script>
```

I get this warning:

```
[Vue warn]: injection "Symbol(route location)" not found. 
  at <Content pageName="homepage" onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< undefined > > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <Website>
```

and this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: can't access property "fullPath", $setup.myroute is undefined
```

I can't understand how switching to TS would break functioning code.

Comment: TS itself can't cause this. It's something else in your setup, which is unknown. It can be caused by duplicated vue-router packages, or improperly used router plugin, but I don't see a possibility for this.

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced similar issue the fix for me was to change my `tsconfig` modules from `"module": "commonjs",` to `"module": "esnext"` hope it helps